# Hartl test errors - redirect when (not) logged in as wrong user, not allow admin edited

Tags: testing, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, integration-testing, helper

I have a few errors that I can't resolve.  All the tests pass.  If there are errors, I only need to check the test, right?  I only need to check the code if they fail, right?

Below are the errors:

> Error:
>   UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user:
>   ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
>       test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:45:in `block in '
>   bin/rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:43
>
> ---
>
> Error:
>   UsersControllerTest#test_should_not_allow_the_admin_attribute_to_be_edited_via_the_web:
>   ArgumentError: unknown keywords: id, user
>       test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:36:in `block in '
>   bin/rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:33
>
> ---
>
> Error:
>   UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_index_when_not_logged_in:
>   URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80index
>       test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in '
>   bin/rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:10
>
> ---
>
> Error:
>   PasswordResetsTest#test_password_resets:
>   NameError: undefined local variable or method 'expired' for #
>       test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:62:in `block in '
>   bin/rails test test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:10

Below are my files:

```
test/integration/password_resets_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class PasswordResetsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "password resets" do
    get new_password_reset_path
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Invalid email
    post password_resets_path, params: { password_reset: { email: "" } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Valid email
    post password_resets_path,
         params: { password_reset: { email: @user.email } }
    assert_not_equal @user.reset_digest, @user.reload.reset_digest
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Password reset form
    user = assigns(:user)
    # Wrong email
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: "")
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Inactive user
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    # Right email, wrong token
    get edit_password_reset_path('wrong token', email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Right email, right token
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    assert_select "input[name=email][type=hidden][value=?]", user.email
    # Invalid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          params: { email: user.email,
                    user: { password:              "foobaz",
                            password_confirmation: "barquux" } }
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Empty password
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          params: { email: user.email,
                    user: { password:              "",
                            password_confirmation: "" } }
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Valid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          params: { email: user.email,
                    user: { password:              "foobaz",
                            password_confirmation: "foobaz" } }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to user
        #passes w percent now, may need to change
        assert_match(/%#{expired}/i, response.body)

  end
end
```

---

```
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
        @other_user = users(:archer)
  end

    test "should redirect index when not logged in" do
    get :index
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get signup_path
    assert_response :success
  end

    test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

    test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: @user.name,
                                              email: @user.email } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

    test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_not @other_user.admin?
    patch :update, id: @other_user, user: { password:              @other_user.password,
                                            password_confirmation: @other_user.password_confirmation,
                                            admin: true }
    assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?
  end


    test "should redirect update when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    patch :update, user_path(@user), user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

    test "should redirect destroy when not logged in" do
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete user_path(@user)
    end
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect destroy when logged in as a non-admin" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete user_path(@user)
    end
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

end
```

---

Below are supporting files:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

    # Shows all users, delete for sups app but useful for BRBBaby
    def index
        @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to root_url and return unless :active
    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
  end

    def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    def edit
  end

    def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

    def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end


    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

        # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

        # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

---

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController
    def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end
end
```

---

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :get_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]
    def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

    def update
    if params[:user][:password].empty?                  # Case (3)
      @user.errors.add(:password, "can't be empty")
      render 'edit'
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)          # Case (4)
      log_in @user
            @user.update_attribute(:reset_digest, nil)
      flash[:success] = "Password has been reset."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'                                     # Case (2)
    end
  end

    private

        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
      end

        def get_user
          @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
      end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
            unless (@user && @user.activated? &&
              @user.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

        # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @user.password_reset_expired?
        flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end

end
```

---

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

    def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_back_or user
      else
        message  = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

---

```
module SessionsHelper

    # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns true if the given user is the current user.
  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

    # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

    # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
    # FIXES - this was !current_user.nil? and had lots of errors and was fixed with below, but not sure right now how it might affect other parts of app.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

    # Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

    # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
        forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

    # Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.original_url if request.get?
  end

end
```

---

```
module UsersHelper
    # Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 80 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end

end
```

---

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,}/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

    # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
      def User.digest(string)
        cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
        BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
      end

      # Returns a random token.
      def User.new_token
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end

      # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
      def remember
        self.remember_token = User.new_token
        update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
      end

      # Forgets a user.
      def forget
        update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
      end

        # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

        # Activates an account.
    def activate
        update_columns(activated: true, activated_at: Time.zone.now)
        # The above line should count for the below two lines
        # update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    # update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
    end

    # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

    # Sets the password reset attributes.
  def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
        update_columns(reset_digest:  User.digest(reset_token), reset_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends password reset email.
  def send_password_reset_email
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
  end

    # Returns true if a password reset has expired.
  def password_reset_expired?
    reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
  end

    private

        # Converts email to all lower-case.
        def downcase_email
            self.email = email.downcase
        end

        # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
        def create_activation_digest
            self.activation_token  = User.new_token
            self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
        end
end
```

---

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
        log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name:  "",
                                              email: "foo@invalid",
                                              password:              "foo",
                                              password_confirmation: "bar" } }

    assert_template 'users/edit'
  end

    test "successful edit with friendly forwarding" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_redirected_to edit_user_path(@user)
    name  = "Foo Bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name:  name,
                                              email: email,
                                              password:              "",
                                              password_confirmation: "" } }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name,  @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @admin     = users(:michael)
    @non_admin = users(:archer)
  end

  test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do
    log_in_as(@admin)
    get users_path
    assert_template 'users/index'
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
      unless user == @admin
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete'
      end
    end
    assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
      delete user_path(@non_admin)
    end
  end

  test "index as non-admin" do
    log_in_as(@non_admin)
    get users_path
    assert_select 'a', text: 'delete', count: 0
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: "", password: "" } }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

    # Validations may have been cheated; confirm platonic result
    test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                          password: 'password' } }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Simulate a user clicking logout in a second window.
    delete logout_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end

    test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end

  test "login without remembering" do
    # Log in to set the cookie.
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
    # Log in again and verify that the cookie is deleted.
        assert_nil cookies['remember_token']

  end

end
```

---

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  end

    test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                         email: "user@invalid",
                                         password:              "foo",
                                         password_confirmation: "bar" } }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    assert_select 'div.field_with_errors'
  end

    test "valid signup information with account activation" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "Example User",
                                         email: "user@example.com",
                                         password:              "password",
                                         password_confirmation: "password" } }
    end
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    user = assigns(:user)
    assert_not user.activated?
    # Try to log in before activation.
    log_in_as(user)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Invalid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path("invalid token", email: user.email)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Valid token, wrong email
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    # Valid activation token
    get edit_account_activation_path(user.activation_token, email: user.email)
    assert user.reload.activated?
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

end
```

---

```
require 'test_helper'

#######
## Amp up password security in the future
## https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+enforce+password+strength
######

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

    test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

    test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

    test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

    test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                         first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
  end

    test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                           foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
  end

    test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
        duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end

    test "password should be present (nonblank)" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " * 6
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "password should have a minimum length" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end



    test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
    assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
  end
end
```

---

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
    # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Logs in a test user.
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, params: { session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me } }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  private

    # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
end
```

---

Any help would be appreciated.  Let me know if there is any info I can provide or if you have questions for me.  Thank you for your help.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
Error: UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:45:in `block in ' bin/rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:43
```

For this one you've used `patch :update user_path(@user)...` when you should just have `patch user_path(@user)...`

2)

```
Error: UsersControllerTest#test_should_not_allow_the_admin_attribute_to_be_edited_via_the_web: ArgumentError: unknown keywords: id, user test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:36:in `block in ' bin/rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:33
```

This is because you have used `patch :update id: @othr_user ...` instead of `patch user_path(@other_user) ...`

3)

```
Error: UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_index_when_not_logged_in: URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80index test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in ' bin/rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:10
```

`http://www.example.com:80index` is indeed a bad URL and should be `http://www.example.com:80/index`
I'd be guessing that `login_url` is setup incorrectly in your routes file... have a look at what it is and try to add the missing `/`?

**EDIT: Actually I think there might be something else here**
You have `get :index` where all the other tests use an actual test path eg `get users_path`.

4)

```
Error: PasswordResetsTest#test_password_resets: NameError: undefined local variable or method 'expired' for # test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:62:in `block in ' bin/rails test test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:10
```

This line: `assert_match(/%#{expired}/i, response.body)` contains the local variable `expired` but nowhere have you assigned a value to `expired`... what do you intend for this value to be?

Comment: Thanks for your response - The changes don't do anything.  Am I running my tests wrong? `bundle exec rake test`

Comment: "don't do anything" as in you made the changes I suggested and you re-ran the test and they had the exact same errors with the exact same error messages? Or are they different messages? Yes you're calling the tests correctly... (though you can probably try with just `rake test` and see if they get run correctly).